# python plotly - produce plot upon two clicks

Tags: python, onclick, plotly, plotly.graph-objects

Let's suppose I have a plotly `graph_objects.Figure` object containing a scatterplot:

```
y = np.random.rand(10)
x = np.random.rand(10)
names = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E',
        'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'L']
fig = go.FigureWidget()
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
                x=x,
                y=y,
                name='Base scatter',
                mode='markers',
                marker=dict(size=7),
                customdata = names,
                hovertemplate= '<b>x:</b> %{x}<br><b>y:</b> %{y}<br><b>Name:</b> %{customdata}<br>'))

fig.update_layout(title='Test')
fig.show()
```

Which produces the following image:
[image]

I would like that upon click on **two** different points, a new temporary plot appears with information about the two points (e.g. those two points in another canvas connected by a line).

I've looked into [click handlers](https://plotly.com/python/click-events/) but I can't figure out how to make it work.

Thanks

Comment: Look at this https://community.plotly.com/t/displaying-image-on-point-hover-in-plotly/9223/12

Comment: This only seems to work for Dash.